# How could I prove $\limsup(A_n) \cap \limsup(B_n) ⊃ \limsup(A_n\cap B_n)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How could I prove (limsupnAn) ∩ (limsupnBn) ⊃ limsupn (An ∩ Bn)

which is (limsupnAn) ∩ (limsupnBn) ⊃ limsupn (An ∩ Bn)

I already know how def of limsup and liminf in set theory.

Comment: Please format your post using MathJax. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a tutorial/quick reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\limsup \{E_n\} = \bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{n=k}^{\infty}E_n
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
x\in \bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{n=k}^{\infty}A_n\cap B_n 
&\iff&
\forall k\geq 1, x\in \bigcup_{n=k}^{\infty}A_n\cap B_n \\
&\iff& 
\forall k\geq 1, \exists n \geq k, x\in A_n\cap B_n \\
&\iff& 
\forall k\geq 1, \exists n \geq k, x\in A_n \text{ and } x\in B_n \\
&\implies& 
\forall k\geq 1, \exists n \geq k, x\in A_n \text{ and } 
\forall k\geq 1, \exists n \geq k,x\in B_n \\
&\iff&
x\in \limsup\{A_n\} \text{ and } x\in\limsup\{B_n\}\\
&\iff&
x\in \limsup\{A_n\} \cap \limsup\{B_n\}
\end{eqnarray*}

Thus,
$$
\limsup\{A_n\cap B_n\} \subset \limsup\{A_n\}\cap \limsup\{B_n\}
$$

Comment: thanks It's exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

$x \in \limsup_n (A_n \cap B_n)$ iff $\{n: x \in A_n \cap B_n\}$ is infinite.

As $\{n: x \in A_n \cap B_n\} \subseteq \{n: x \in A_n \} \cap \{n: x \in B_n\}$, the set $\{n: x \in A_n \}$ is also infinite, i.e. $x \in \limsup_n A_n$, and $\{n: x \in B_n \}$ is also infinite, hence $x \in \limsup_n B_n$. This shows the inclusion.

For $\liminf_n A_n \cap B_n$ the analogous inclusion holds, as the intersection of two cofinite sets of $\Bbb N$ is again cofinite.